# mongodb dot notation with $pop

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Using MongoDB, (web console available [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-mongodb-terminal)) I have some data:

```
db.foo.insert({
    item: "stuff", 
    qty: 17,
    test: {
        bob: 1,
        alice: 2,
        candice: 3,
        myarray: ["a","b","c","d"]
    }
})
```

How do I pop from myarray?

I've tried:

```
db.foo.update(
    {'test.bob':1},
    { $pop: {'test.myarray': -1}}
)
```

and:

```
db.foo.update(
    {'test.bob': 1},
    { $pop: {'test': {'myarray': -1}}}
)
```

I know the query portion is correct, just not the $pop portion, because the following returns a correct result:

```
db.foo.find(
    {'test.bob': 1}
)
```

I've researched [$pop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/), [dot-notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation), a [random question](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/134mga71pt/pull-dot-notation) I found that had no response, and even a [github commit](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1039/commits/740d79b50d85f2568f699527bdb2e5bd91101795) that shows a working example of nearly what I'm trying to do (albeit with a $pull instead of a $pop on line 357). The error code I keep receiving is:

> SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):3:6

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code listed in the question actually works: I was using an older version of MongoDB likely when that feature was not added. Another poster mentioned this but for some reason the answer has disappeared.

For reference, use `db.version()` to get the version
The version running on [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-mongodb-terminal) at the time of this post is 3.2.4, which is not the current version of Mongo (which is 3.6 at the time of this post).